# When I try to do a batch magick convert -flatten command on a directory, it fails

Tags: imagemagick

I'm, trying to flatten a whole directory of .png images to have a white background.

The following command works on a single file:

```
magick convert -flatten "c:\Users\LibrarySurface2\OneDrive\Pictures\2016-08-09 archive of coworking space feedback\20151214 115702.png" "c:\Users\LibrarySurface2\OneDrive\Pictures\2016-08-09 archive of coworking space feedback\20151214 115702-white.png"
```

...however when I try to run it against the whole directory (1300 or so images) using the following command:

```
magick convert -flatten *.png *-w.png
```

It fails out with a bunch of these, and then stops running because of "too many exceptions" any thoughts on what could be causing this?

convert: Expected 3949 bytes; found 2684 bytes `.\20160426 114948.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1683.
convert: Read Exception`.\20160426 114948.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1650.
convert: corrupt image `.\20160426 114948.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/4029.
convert: Expected 4585 bytes; found 929 bytes`.\20160429 145040.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1683.
convert: Read Exception `.\20160429 145040.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1650.
convert: corrupt image`.\20160429 145040.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/4029.
convert: Expected 8192 bytes; found 8037 bytes `.\20160504 165938.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1683.
convert: Read Exception`.\20160504 165938.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1650.
convert: corrupt image `.\20160504 165938.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/4029.

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup first, then use `mogrify` instead:

```
mogrify -flatten *.png
```

Explanation: In general, use the `convert` command when you want one output file and `mogrify` when you want multiple output files.